# Storing mysqli connection in object

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to contain my mysqli object within a class, that other objects/scripts can use. I initialize it like so:

```
        $this->host         = $Host;
    $this->username     = $UName;
    $this->password     = $PWord;
    $this->database     = $DBName;
    $this->debugEmail   = $debugEmail;

    // Create sql handler
    $this->conn = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);

    // Check connection
    if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection Failed: " . $this->conn->connect_error());
    }
```

The problem is when I use this object elsewhere, it seems to think that the conn object is null.

For example:

```
$sqlObj = new sqlObject();
$sqlObj->init();

// run query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = $sqlObj->getConn()->query($sql);
```

It returns:

```
Call to a member function query() on a non-object
```

Comment: You should post your class definition, some details are unclear in your question. For example: how is `getConn()` defined? We cannot _guess_ that.

Comment: And a side note: `sqlObject` is not a good name for such a class or object. An object of this class is not `sql`, is it? It is a database connection. So call it like that, this way your code gets easier to understand.

Comment: `it seems to think` error messages are seldomly wrong. This means your object is not constructed correctly when called from elsewhere. Are you using `getConn()` in the *working* example? maybe the function does not actually return the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly $sqlObj->getConn() is returning null or false (or another object) that isn't the desired type.
I recommend you to throw a new error in getConn() and wrap with a try/catch block. In this throw, return the error coming from getConn and you'll be able to understand it better. BTW, Are the connection params ok ? It seems to be something related to this.

Comment: I've changed the $conn variable from an internal private variable to a global variable inside the sqlObject.php file, and this fixed it. This suggests to me that the line: $this->conn = new mysqli() was falling out of scope at the end of the init() function.